# $M=K\oplus I$ iff there exists an idempotent $\phi \in End_R(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have a ring R and an R-module M.
I want to show that $M=K\oplus I$, where $K=Ker(\phi)$ and $I=Im(\phi)$ iff there exists an idempotent $\phi \in End_R(M)$

I am happy showing that if $\phi$ is idempotent, then M is the direct sum of the kernel and the image of $\phi$. But I am not sure how to go in the other direction.

Suppose $M=K\oplus I$.  Then $Im(\phi) \cap Ker (\phi) = 0$

What is the next step from here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M=K\oplus I$. Deffine $\phi:M\to M$ by $$M\to I \to M$$ where the first map is the projection and the second is the inclusion. I let you show that $\phi$ is idempotent and that $K=Ker(\phi)$ and $I=Im(\phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $M = K \oplus I$ where $K$ and $I$ are $R$-modules, what you need to do is *construct* an idempotent map $\phi$ that satisfies $K = \ker \phi$ and $I = im(\phi)$.

The key is to define the map by
$$
\phi(x_K + x_I) = x_I
$$
where $x_K \in K$ and $x_I \in I$.